# What is the harmonic conjugate of $u=4xy-3x+5y$?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

What is the harmonic conjugate of $u=4xy-3x+5y$?
I got $u'x=4-y=v'y$
then I integrated $v'y$ to get $v= 2y^2-3y+h(x)$.

Then I did $-u'y=v'x$
so, $5= h'(x)$ then I integrated $5$ with respect to $x$ to get $5x$
and so, my harmonic conjugate should be $v=5x+c$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Very hard to understand. I think you should read the directions to write mathematics in this site. Anyway, if $\;u(x,y)=4xy-3x+5y\;$ , then definitely  $\;u_x'\neq v'_y\;$ , and also $\;u'_x=4y-3\;$ Check this, please.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand $100\%$ of what you done there, but it seems to me that you differentiated something wrong in the beginning.

You want $v(x,y)$ such that $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}, \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x},$$that is: $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(x,y) = 4y-3, \quad \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y) = -4x-5.$$From the first one, we get $v(x,y) = 2y^2-3y + h(x)$. Then $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y) = h'(x) = -4x-5$, whence $h(x) = -2x^2-5x+c$. We conclude that: $$v(x,y) = -2x^2 + 2y^2-5x -3y + c, \quad c \in \Bbb R.$$One readily checks that $\nabla^2v = 0$, as desired.